# how properly see jdbcTemplate after execution failed/success?

Tags: java, ajax, jdbctemplate

I'm using jdbcTemplate.query to execute data from ajax html to update data oracle. everythings seems ok during execution by means no error appeared. but when look on database, I just realise there's no change in it ..

so, i need to know in which part i missed. here, my code :

1. ajax :

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: data,
      method: 'post',
      success(  response) {
        alert('response updateTow Op: %O'+ JSON.stringify(response))
      },
      error : function(e) {
    alert("show error : " + JSON.stringify(e)); 
  }
    })
```

2. DAO :

```
@Value("${update.daMain}")
private String updateDaMain;

@Value("${update.daStand}")
private String updateDaStand;

@Override
public int update(DataModel data) {

    int updated = 0;
    Object[] paramDaMain = {data.getContact(), data.geStatus(),data.getPriority(),data.getId()};

    Object[] paramDaParking = {data.getParkingId() , data.getParkingSeq()};

    updated += this.jdbcTemplate.update(updateDaMain, paramDaMain);
    updated += this.jdbcTemplate.update(updateDaStand,paramDaParking);

    return updated;
}
```

3. xml 1):

```
<entry key="update.daMain">
    <![CDATA[UPDATE da_main 
    SET CONTACT = ? 
    , STATUS = ?
    , PRIORITY = ?
     WHERE ID = ?]]>
</entry>
```

xml 2) :

```
        <entry key="update.daStand">
    <![CDATA[UPDATE DA_PARKING
        SET PARKING_ID = ?
        WHERE PARKING_SEQ = ?]]></entry>
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess you're running this code in transactional mode and not committed the transaction

Comment: i'm not sure it's needed @AnirudhSimha, but if it's necessary you can show me it should write in which part ?

Comment: I'm not saying its required.But since I don't know the entire context of your application, it was just an educated guess...Anyways, If you are using spring, you should annotate db modifying methods with @Transactional

Comment: thx god, i just found my mistake .. the variable in html not all declared in DAO & XML .. thx for your response @AnirudhSimha